# Alert firing postback after confirmation asp.net button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, alert

I have some strange thing with javascript alert in my asp.net application. I have button that need delete user from database. But user can have documents, and also can have insurance policies. 
So I want to fire javascript alert if user have any documents or policy. That alert will say "You need delete documents and/or policies. But if user don't have any of them then need to fire confirmation box where you need choose do you want delete or not.
So my .aspx code looks like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger" runat="server" Text="Izbriši" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" 
                                                                onClientClick="check()">
                                                            </asp:Button>
```

and function check()

```
function check() {
            var totalRows = $("#<%=gvDocuments.ClientID %> tr").length-1;
            var totalRows1 = $("#<%=gvPolice.ClientID %> tr").length-1;
            if (totalRows > 0 || totalRows1 > 0) {
                alert('Izbrišite ' + totalRows + ' dokumenta i ' + totalRows1 + ' polica klijenta prije nego ga možete izbrisati!');
//Here I check and count is there any documents or policies
                return false;
            }
            else {
                var r = confirm('Jeste li sigurni da želite izbrisati klijenta?')
                if (r == true) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

So my confirm block is functioning. You presss OK and delete, or cancel and it returns false.
But I dont know when user press ok on **alert** he fires postback and delete user so documents and everything stays live or as I understand returns true?
Thank you,
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect your button in the browser and you'll see that Asp.net will simply execute its doPostback javascript (in line, or on the form submit) immediately after your onclientclick code!

So your function call will return true/false, then the doPostback will execute anyway.

What you need to do is handle the return of your function inline like this:

```
onClientClick="if(check() === false){return false;}"
```

Only by returning false here, will you interrupt the javascript, and the postback won't fire :)

Comment: Thank you works like a charm. I found soulution like this but I thouth that it will return false even if click it in confirmation.